# View state and application design

Tags: c++, model-view-controller, c++11

I have a toolbar controller which is capable of updating the toolbar state ( enabled/disabled, pressed/unpressed ) by querying document properties or the application framework.  I have some buttons that represent the current state of a view.

From an application design standpoint I like having toolbar controller able to update the button state at any time given a document.  I also prefer the toolbar controller & button handlers to have no internal state.

Options as I see it - looking for other suggestions:

- Create a mechanism for visiting all views of a document with a visitor that can capture the state of the view which is then used to enable/disable/press/depress the button.
- Create some connection between views and toolbar handlers that allows the toolbar buttons to directly ask the views.
- Other??

Answer (score 0):

you can try having an event loop for the view and update the state with a function call dispatch

Like this:

```
class ViewEventArgs{
   public:
    int eventNumber;
};
class ViewEvent{
    public:
   virtual void onViewChange(ViewEventChangeArgs args) = 0;
};

class ViewController{
    public:
   virtual void doPressed() = 0;
   virtual void doChecked() = 0;
   //other interface methods
};

class ToolbarView : public ViewEvent{
   public:
   //Your EVENT-LOOP kernel will fire these events depending upon the state change in the view
   void onViewChange(ViewEventChangeArgs args)
   {
       switch(args.eventNumber){
    case PRESSED:
       getToolbarController()->doPressed();//the method dispatch
       break;
    case CHECKED:
       getToolbarController()->doChecked();
       }      
   }
    //other parts of the view
};

class ToolbarController: public ViewController{
    public:
       void doPressed() { /*pressed*/ }
       void doChecked() { /*checked*/ }
           //implementations
};
```

Comment: Trying to understand.  The view would push its state to the toolbar controller via function call disbatch?  Wouldn't this require the toolbar controller to register with the view?

Comment: yeah, you would need to register with the view. But this would be something like View::setToolbarController(aToolBarController). aToolBarController would need to have IMPLEMENTED from a purely virtual class, having ONLY virtual methods[aka INTERFACE]. This will set up the dispatch mechanism quite nicely, allowing for MULTIPLE toolbar controllers.